# Displaying .jpg file in ArcMap for georeferencing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing, basemap

I'm struggling to georeference a .jpg map. When I load it in to ArcMap, I cannot see the picture at all, so I cannot georeference it. I tried to zoom to the map layer but the map just does not appear.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trying to zoom to layer you need to use the [georeferencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000000mp000000) toolbar to display your .jpg

Once you have the .jpg in your table of contents, navigate to where your image will be georeferenced (assuming you have a basemap) you can then open the drop-down and select fit to display:

[image: Fit to display]

This will center the image on your screen allowing you to start the georef process with it roughly in the right location.