# calculating sq ft of an picture image with only a scale bar as reference

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, cad, imagej

I have an architectural image of a building. However, I had to change the blueprint and extend the walls out further increasing the total sq.ft., and simply for the means of drawing out the new building dimensions, I pulled the image into arcmap so I could digitize the lines on the image and represent the new blueprint suggestion in a different color. Pulling this jpeg into arcmap clearly has no reference to calculate sq.ft., however, there is a scale bar in the corner of the picture. Unfortunately, this building is not a standard shape like a rectangle or something that would allow easy math and using a ruler to measure the perimeter and calculate the new sq ft total.

I do not know CAD. Is there any way within arcmap to trace over the scale bar and tell the software this scale bar line represents 100 ft and then from there it uses that as a reference so I can trace the whole building perimeter and it will calculate sq. ft?

The only other thing that vaguely stands out in my mind is the "Image J" software. Would this be an option for what I need to do?

Comment: when you say "I pulled the image into arcmap" does this mean it is to scale within arcmap? Meaning is the image now georefrenced?

Comment: @Dan , No the image cannot be georeferenced, so it is not to scale. I only pulled in the .jpg by "adding data" and then digitized lines over the image without any reference, just to simply neatly draw lines on the page instead of hand drawing them with a pencil. However, this image does have a scale bar in the corner so as long as I didn't change the overall image dimensions I would assume I could utilize this scale bar in some way.

Comment: why can you not geo-reference the image?

Comment: @ed.hankins atleast I believe I cannot, but I could be wrong. The image I have is of a small building that does not yet exist and the picture does not show any surrounding area to manually georeference. The image is not an aerial either, it's simply an architectural rendering blueprint on blank white paper.

Comment: @Dan okay, I guess what I'm asking then is how to georeference an image using only a scale bar with measurements ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a couple of questions in one...  How do I georeference a JPG and How do I measure objects.

You are going to have to georeference the JPG using the [Georeferencing](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/georeferencing-toolbar-tools.htm) toolbar if you want to use ArcMap for spatial analysis.  I am not sure which version of desktop you are using but you can see this [SO post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129525/how-to-display-a-jpg-file-in-arcmap-for-georeferencing) and [this tutorial](http://www.library.yale.edu/MapColl/files/docs/Georeferencing%20of%20Scanned%20Maps.pdf) in order to accomplish this. After you georeference the image you have two options.

1. Use the measurment tool.
2. Create a new shapefile (polygon) by tracing your building and calculate values on the new object.

[Here is an example](http://courses.umass.edu/nrc592g-cschweik/pdfs/Georeferencing_a_map.pdf) of how to do it with a scanned image.

Comment: this image cannot be georeferenced. please see the comments above to ed.hankins

Comment: If you have a scale bar you can georefrence the image (but you don't have have one to georefrence). You may have to print it out and create some distance measurements in order to accomplish this if there are none on the image already.  You could also overly it on a basemap for a distance reference.  You may need to create a new question and post the image and ask "how do i georefrence this"

Comment: I do have a scale bar on the image. I thought that's exactly what I was asking through this question and with the question title I wrote. Okay, maybe I need to rephrase it. Do you know how to georeference with only a scale bar?

Comment: There are two examples above on how to do this if you do not like them or they are not clear...Google "georefrence JPG arcmap" and there are thousands of tutorials and videos.  Then you are going to have to work through at least one of them and then say I tried X based on Y and am stuck on Z. And someone can help you based on that.